# How to send django exception log manually?

Tags: django, exception, logging

I have a specific view in my app which should return `HttpResponse('')` if everything was done successfully and smth like `HttpResponseBadRequest()` otherwise.

This view works with external data so some unexpected exceptions can be raised.
Of course I need to know what happened. So I have smth like that:

```
def my_view(request):
    try:
        # a lot of code
        return HttpResponse('')
    except:
        import logging
        logger = logging.getLogger('django.request')
        # logger.error(extra={'request': request}) or logger.exception()
        return HttpResponseBadRequest('')
```

I have a default logging config if it matters (django 1.5).

`logger.exception` sends only a small traceback and no request data.
`logger.error` sends only request data.

So the question is how to get exactly the same traceback as django sends (with the same subject/body)).
I think there must be some clean and simple solution that i just can't find.

#### UPDATE

So with the patched `exception` method i ended up with the following code:

```
logger.exception('Internal Server Error: %s', request.path,
                 extra={'status_code': 500, 'request': request})
```

which produces equal email traceback as built-in django logging.

Comment: can you show us your django logging config (from settings file)?

Comment: I use default logging (don't set my own `LOGGING` in settings.py). Anyway I got my answer (see update).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is due to a bug which has been fixed in recent versions of Python 2.7. [This bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue15541) meant that the `exception` method did not accept the `extra` argument.

If you can't upgrade to a suitably recent Python 2.7, then you can perhaps patch your Python with the fix referenced in the issue I've linked to. If you can't do that, you'll need to subclass `Logger` and override the `exception` method to do the right thing (which is basically to add a `**kwargs` to the `exception` method's signature, which is passed through to its call to the `error` method.

Comment: Thanks. One of those things that can be expected (I mean python bug). Unfortunately my OS is ubuntu 12.04 which has python 2.7.3 on board and it can't be updated to 2.7.5 easily. But I've manually patched built-in logging module and now everything works fine. See my update.